# How to implement Slide Effect in bxslider for Ajax generated li's content

Tags: bxslider

Currently I am implemented a bxslider with ajax generated li's. Everything is fine in ajax requests & content is fetching fine. I also added bxslider navigation code in to ajax navigation.

My problem is that: While using ajax navigation buttons, slider effect of bxslider is not working.

My bxslider code is here:

```
     $(document).ready(function(){
           myReadyFunction();
     }); 

function myReadyFunction(){

        var slider = $('#moreStories').bxSlider({
                             mode: 'horizontal',
                             speed:900,
                             controls: true,
                             pager: false,
                             displaySlideQty: 3,
                             moveSlideQty:1,
                             ticker: false,
                      });

       $('#go_prev').live("click", function(){
           ///alert("prev");
               slider.goToPreviousSlide();
            return false;
      });

      $('#go_next').live("click", function(){
        //alert("next");
        top.window.close();
        slider.goToNextSlide();
        return false;
      });

}
```

And below is my code to access ajax content via jquery:

```
function loadData(page)
{
     loading_show();    
     $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
       url: "load_page.php",
       data: "page="+page,
       success: function(msg){
          $(".ajaxBased").ajaxComplete(function(event, request, settings){
            loading_hide();
            $(".ajaxBased").html(msg);
          });
         }
      });
}
    loadData(1);  // For first time page load default results
    $('.ajaxBased #navigation a.active').live('click',function(){
        var page = $(this).attr('p');
        loadData(page)
    });
```

Can anybody help me to get out this slider problem, I have also search the forum, but could't find exact solution.

Comment: Are you redrawing the slider after the ajax success?